# accessing function's local variables in another project

Tags: python, function

```
#project login.py
def login():
    username = input()
    password = input()
    #did some stuff!

#now a new project...    

#project access.py 
from login import login

if login.username=='ABC' and login.password=='XYZ': 
    #Cool...gained access!
```

My problem is I am not getting how to access these local variables...
Is there any other way except making username and password the args of login?

Comment: actually i want to enter username,password values trough access.py and get login.py's result in the access.py project...

Answer (score 0):

```
#project login.py

def login():
    username = input()
    password = input()
    #did some stuff!
    return username, password

#now a new project...    

#project access.py 
from login import login

username, password = login()
if username=='ABC' and password=='XYZ': 
    #Cool...gained access!
```

You need to make the results available in your access.py code

Comment: I'm confused.  Your original question asked how to access username and password, no?